# Android libVLC build: linker fails with various undefined references

Tags: c++, android-ndk, linker-errors, clang++, libvlc

I'm trying to build libVLC for usage within an Android application (I can't find pre-built libs for all the platforms I am targeting). I am using Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS server and am following the [Android compile instructions](https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile) and installed the packages mentioned there. I have the NDK r13 and SDK r24.4.1, essentially both freshly downloaded.

I started the process with `./compile.sh -a arm --release -l`

Everything *seems* to compile correctly, but then I end up with linker errors. Here's the output starting from what seems most relevant:

```
Generating static module list
/home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/toolchains/arm/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm: libiconv.a: File format not recognized
/home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/toolchains/arm/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-objcopy:vlc/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/modules/.libs/libgnutls_plugin.a(libiconv.a): Unable to recognise the format of file: File format not recognized
Package zlib was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `zlib.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'zlib', required by '/libvncclient', not found
Building NDK
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:vlc: non-system libraries in linker flags: /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libandroid_window_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libadf_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libsubsdec_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libps_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libkaraoke_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libtaglib_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/liboldmovie_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libconsole_logger_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libshm_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libcompressor_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libcroppadd_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libiomx_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libchorus_flanger_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libgles2_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/liboggspots_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libnormvol_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libstereo_widen_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/librtp_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/liblpcm_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libspatializer_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libes_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libpostproc_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libfps_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libdemux_stl_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libfreetype_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libttml_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libcache_block_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libpacketizer_copy_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libstl_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libmemory_keystore_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libpva_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libflacsys_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/liblogo_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/librecord_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libflac_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libi420_nv12_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libaes3_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libtimecode_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libdvdread_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libsubsusf_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libcc_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libmarq_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libwav_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libdecomp_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libpacketizer_mpegaudio_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libi420_rgb_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/liblua_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/liba52_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libxml_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libcache_read_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libdsm_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libyuy2_i422_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libadjust_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libogg_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libvhs_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libgaussianblur_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libegl_android_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libpng_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libts_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/librawvideo_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libgnutls_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libpacketizer_mpeg4video_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libdummy_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libsoxr_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libtransform_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libfile_keystore_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libvolume_neon_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libsubsdelay_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libspeex_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libremap_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libpacketizer_mpegvideo_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libvc1_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libinvert_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libftp_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libpacketizer_dirac_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libchain_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libinteger_mixer_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/librotate_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libaudio_format_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libfile_logger_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libmkv_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libcaf_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libau_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libmediacodec_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libvdr_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libtelx_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libcdg_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libg711_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libnfs_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libfilesystem_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libnsv_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libmjpeg_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/liblibass_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libvpx_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libmono_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libsubsttml_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libsyslog_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libpacketizer_hevc_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libadpcm_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libsatip_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libvmem_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/liblive555_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libpacketizer_avparser_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libty_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libhttp_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libzvbi_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libedgedetection_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libwave_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libcanvas_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libimem_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libsubstx3g_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libsepia_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libi420_yuy2_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libvobsub_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libyuv_rgb_neon_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libgrey_yuv_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libscaletempo_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libspdif_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libfluidsynth_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libdvdnav_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libparam_eq_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libgain_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libadaptive_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libdemux_cdg_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libupnp_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/librar_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libpacketizer_mlp_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libaccess_concat_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libcolorthres_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libcvdsub_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libnsc_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libxa_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libplaylist_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libdemuxdump_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libi422_yuy2_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libtospdif_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libandroid_audiotrack_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libinflate_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libmpgv_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libscte18_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libavformat_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libopensles_android_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libflaschen_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libprefetch_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libmp4_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libattachment_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libhds_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libugly_resampler_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libmod_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libfingerprinter_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libaraw_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libaccess_mms_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libextract_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libyuy2_i420_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libzip_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libdiracsys_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libsvcdsub_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libfreeze_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libdvbsub_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libamem_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libscale_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libtta_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libblend_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libh26x_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/librv32_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libavi_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libequalizer_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libandroid_logger_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libudp_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libscte27_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libavcodec_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libyuvp_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libavio_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libfloat_mixer_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libpacketizer_vc1_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libaiff_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libsdp_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libdeinterlace_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libchroma_yuv_neon_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libaccess_realrtsp_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libhttps_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/librawaud_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libuleaddvaudio_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libswscale_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libasf_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libvoc_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libgradfun_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libtrivial_channel_mixer_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libmpg123_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libaccess_archive_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libmicrodns_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/librawdv_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libhqdn3d_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libi422_i420_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libafile_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libsimple_channel_mixer_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libantiflicker_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libpacketizer_dts_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libheadphone_channel_mixer_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libsftp_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libvorbis_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libpacketizer_flac_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/librawvid_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libanaglyph_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libtcp_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libtheora_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libspudec_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libopus_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libnuv_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libdolby_surround_decoder_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libpacketizer_h264_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libi420_10_p010_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libimage_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libandroid_native_window_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libfolder_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libjpeg_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libpacketizer_mpeg4audio_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libsubtitle_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/.modules/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/libpacketizer_a52_plugin.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/vlc/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/lib/.libs/libvlc.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/vlc/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/src/.libs/libvlccore.a /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/vlc/build-android-arm-linux-androideabi/compat/.libs/libcompat.a -ldvdnav -ldvdread -ldvdcss -ldvdread -ldvdcss -lFLAC -logg -lfluidlite -lvorbisfile -lvorbis -logg -lfreetype -lfribidi -lgnutls /home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/vlc/contrib/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/libiconv.a -lgmp -lharfbuzz -lhogweed -lgmp -lnettle -larchive -lass -liconv -lfribidi -lfreetype -lavcodec -lopenjpeg -lgsm -lavutil -lavformat -lopenjpeg -lgsm -lavcodec -lopenjpeg -lgsm -lavutil -lavutil -ldsm -ldvbpsi -ldvdcss -lebml -lmatroska -lebml -lmodplug -lmpg123 -lnfs -lpng16 -lpng16 -lpostproc -lavutil -lssh2 -lgcrypt -lgpg-error -lswscale -lavutil -ltasn1 -lupnp -lthreadutil -lixml -lxml2 -lmicrodns -lnettle -logg -lopus -lprotobuf-lite -lprotobuf -lsoxr -lspeexdsp -lspeex -ltag_c -ltag -ltag -ltheoradec -logg -ltheoraenc -ltheoradec -logg -ltheora -logg -lvorbisenc -lvorbisfile -lvorbis -logg -lvpx -lzvbi -liconv -lpng -lliveMedia -lUsageEnvironment -lBasicUsageEnvironment -lgroupsock -la52 -ljpeg -lavcodec -lebml -llua -lc++abi -landroid_support  
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the
Android NDK:     current module
make: Entering directory `/home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/libvlc'
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : vlc <= libvlcjni-modules.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : vlc <= libvlcjni-symbols.c
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: vlc <= dummy.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Prebuilt       : libc++_shared.so <= <NDK>/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/armeabi-v7a/
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libvlc.so
../../modules/lua/vlc.c:219: error: undefined reference to 'config_GetLibDir'
../../modules/lua/vlc.c:229: error: undefined reference to 'config_GetDataDir'
../../modules/lua/libs/configuration.c:110: error: undefined reference to 'config_GetDataDir'
../../modules/arm_neon/volume.c:49: error: undefined reference to 'vlc_CPU'
../../modules/arm_neon/yuv_rgb.c:137: error: undefined reference to 'vlc_CPU'
../../modules/video_filter/deinterlace/deinterlace.c:696: error: undefined reference to 'vlc_CPU'
../../modules/arm_neon/chroma_yuv.c:220: error: undefined reference to 'vlc_CPU'
../../src/misc/threads.c:89: error: undefined reference to 'vlc_addr_timedwait'
../../src/misc/threads.c:148: error: undefined reference to 'vlc_addr_signal'
../../src/misc/threads.c:154: error: undefined reference to 'vlc_addr_broadcast'
../../src/misc/threads.c:173: error: undefined reference to 'vlc_addr_wait'
../../src/misc/threads.c:197: error: undefined reference to 'vlc_addr_timedwait'
../../src/misc/threads.c:148: error: undefined reference to 'vlc_addr_signal'
../../src/misc/threads.c:154: error: undefined reference to 'vlc_addr_broadcast'
../../src/misc/threads.c:148: error: undefined reference to 'vlc_addr_signal'
../../src/misc/messages.c:121: error: undefined reference to 'vlc_thread_id'
../../src/android/thread.c:321: error: undefined reference to 'vlc_addr_broadcast'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [jni/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libvlc.so] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/builder/vlc-build/vlc-android/libvlc'
ndk-build failed for libvlc
```

There's a few things worrying in there like the warning about non-system libraries (but isn't that expected since it is a cross-compile?) but they don't seem to connect to the issue.

I can't seem to find anything relevant in Google nor on Stackoverflow (except maybe [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606044/building-native-library-with-standalone-toolchain-android-arm) hinting perhaps I should try an older version of the NDK?) as these seem to all be functionality provided by VLC itself. As a result I'm also not sure where to look in the compile process' logs or output to find other hints of things being awry. What else should I post?

Answer (score 0):

I'm rather late to the party but posting anyways.
`Package zlib was not found in the pkg-config search path.`
[Missing dependencies surface as totally irrelevant errors sadly.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40437692/error-compiling-libvlc-for-android/43036251#43036251)

Comment: I think I tried that, but I can't remember. I eventually deleted the VM; I've tried starting this again to verify your answer but I'm running into a different set of issues anyway :/